# How to calculate volume of 3d convex hull?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry, 3d

Convex hull is defined by a set of planes (point on plane, plane normal).
I also know the plane intersections points which form polygons on each face.

**How to calculate volume of convex hull?**

Comment: This is a difficult problem. See [Algorithm for finding the volume of a convex polytope](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have the plane intersections too, It is equivalent to the volume of a polyhedron. (the fact that yours is convex doesn't matter).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume

Answer (score 4):

Find a point $O$ within the hull.  Then add up the volumes of the cones made by $O$ and each face.  Volume of each cone is $\frac{1}{3}\times \text{(height)}\times \text{(area of face)}$