# I have a convex hull (generated from a library) in 3D. I only have the vertices. How do I compute the volume of the hull.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a library (quickhull in C++) that I am using to create a hull from a set of points. I am able to see the vertices of the hull but not the facets. I would like to compute the volume of the hull. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope .  I believe qhull has approximate volume computation in 3D.

Comment: I don't want to use qhull - it's not possible to easily integrate it into my code (written in C++). I am using this library: https://github.com/akuukka/quickhull

Comment: There is a C++ interface to qhull, check the website.  At any rate, my point is that there isn't a good, explicit way to do this unless you have the faces, which if you did you could compute face areas and add up cone volumes (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60279/how-to-calculate-volume-of-3d-convex-hull?rq=1)).  If you only have the point cloud, triangulating it is definitely possible but fairly slow.   Approximate methods to compute volumes of convex hulls are mostly Monte Carlo based (i.e. random), and I believe this is what qhull uses.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will see if i can get the faces of the hull.

Comment: Calculate *inner point* of convex hull (simple mean of vertices). Then summarize all the volumes for all simplices constructed from inner point + facet of convex hull.