# calculating the volume of irregular shape from coordinates

Tags: general-topology, geometry, 3d, estimation

Let's say we have a shape with coordinates as $(X_1,Y_1,Z_1,X_2,Y_2,Z_2,\dots,X_n,Y_n,Z_n)$ in the 3D space where each point is connected to all other points.
Is there a way to **estimate** the volume that this shape occupies in space?

I believe this is a very general problem and there should be a famous theorem somewhere that pertains to it. Is it possible to solve for an exact solution analytically?

Comment: I recommended starting with the simplest case first, which would be four points (not all coplanar). See if you can work out the volume formula for four arbitrary points, then decide if you really want it generalized to n points. Hint: three points define a plane, so adding the fourth point will give you what can be viewed as a skewed irregular pyramid.

Comment: Another related concept: the [Convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the points is the shape you are trying to get the volume of.

Comment: Thank you all, it seems my question is kind of a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60279/how-to-calculate-volume-of-3d-convex-hull